# Cat leaped on me while sleeping and bit my lip!

Tags: cats

I am a senior--My cat and I usually take a nap in late afternoon. Oreo sleeps close to me. We were not playing before the nap, but in the past playing has led to an aggressive bite--After which I yell "bad cat" and slap him. Therefore, Oreo must know to bite is not good. I am a mouth breather and sleep with my mouth open.While I was sleeping, My cat leaped on me and bit my lip also scratching my chin as I bolted awake. Perhaps this is just a game, but because of it, I can never trust my cat to sleep with me again!The lip bite was actually very bloody-and I am very upset, as Oreo is 8 years old and I have had him since he was a kitten.I love my furry kitty, but this is the worse thing a cat Ive owned, has ever done and I have had 6 other cats! My buddy has turned on me and I am not happy!